# Correlation in new line-LoadRunner

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

Hi guys I'm new to LoadRunner and I'm trying to get the following number: `3185`, 
but this number is changing - it's dynamic and it's always between 2 lines as you can see in the following example . I tried using:

`web_reg_save_param("var", "LB=Internal ID=176)", "RB=________", "Ord=All", LAST);`

but it's not working. 
I'm not able to get the dynamic number, as in this example : `3185`.

Can anyone help me please?

```
Action.c(862): t=29925ms: 4-byte response body for "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=176)
Action.c(862):     3185
Action.c(862): web_custom_request("test_2") was successful, 4 body bytes, 209
```

Comment: Has your management sent you through training and provided you with a mentor for your first several gigs, up to a year....?

Comment: Could you please provide the actual sample response from which you're trying to extract the number? You say it's between 2 lines, what two lines?

Comment: -Michael Galos   between (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=176) and web_custom_request("test_2")

Comment: thank  Michael Galos